what are the conditions that make the status changed from Reviewing Completed to Reviewers Assigned?
I got major revision and the status was under review for the 2 reviewers from 10/7/2024 and go Reviewing Completed in 26/7/2024 but the status become Reviewers Assigned after sometime.
Does that mean it will enter to the reviewing process again ?
Does any delay with the second reviewer so the editor will search for another one ?
I need to know form the experts the conditions that make the status changed from Reviewing Completed to Reviewers Assigned

For this and all such questions, see: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55665/75368

i hope to find the answer in the post but i have a specific question in this case and i searched for the answer in the post but couldn't find it

Since that is a canonical question, any answer to this question should be placed there, not here. I hesitate to vote to close as a duplicate as I have too much power in such matters. But, yes, the meaning of "reviewers assigned" is discussed in that question.

@prog: From the proposed duplicate: “Editorial decision: Based on the reviews, the editors decide whether: […] A decision requires further reviews.” This is the case that applies to you. Speculating about the details would be wild guessing and won’t help you. — I need to know […] the conditions that make the status changed from Reviewing Completed to Reviewers Assigned – In all seriousness: Why? How would it help you? Do you need to make a decision based on it? If you can specify that, we may have a useful question.

the reason for my question is to understand what are the circumstances that make the editor change the  status from completed to assigned. Does that mean one of the reviewer reject the paper after major revision or he excused that he couldn't revise it and if that yes how can the reviewing completed then. or does the editor might assign new reviewers to evaluate the revised manuscript.

@prog: the reason for my question is to understand what are the circumstances that make the editor change the status from completed to assigned. – That’s circular. There is a reason why you want to know. For example, you wand to predict the fate of your manuscript (which you cannot). Also that is answered by the duplicate: A decision requires further reviews. There are several reasons for this in turn, but we have no way of knowing, but you might learn them when you eventually receive the reviews.

Review completed means the review was completed. The reviewer finished it and submitted it. The status doesn't say what the recommendation was, but it does say it was finalized.
If your manuscript goes from "review completed" to "reviewers assigned", the most probable explanation is that the editor has decided to get more reviewers. In turn, the most probable reasons for getting more reviewers are 1) divergent reviews, and 2) review(s) submitted was not helpful.
Either way there's nothing to do except wait.

Will the new reviewer review the paper from scratch or will review the comments for the previous reviewers , please

It's usually from scratch. Reviewers don't usually see each other's reviews.
